# Typhoon initial assembly is instance of TyphoonCollaboratingAssemblyProxy

Tags: ios, xcode, dependency-injection, typhoon

I'm new to Typhoon so i can't figure this out..
I have a number of initial assemblies:

```c
@interface ApplicationAssembly : TyphoonAssembly

@property (nonatomic,strong,readonly) ControllersAssemblyImplementation *controllersAssembly;

@end


@interface ControllersAssemblyImplementation : TyphoonAssembly <ControllersAssembly>

@property (nonatomic,strong) ServicesAssemblyImplementation *servicesAssembly;

@end

@interface ServicesAssemblyImplementation : TyphoonAssembly<ServicesAssembly>

@property (nonatomic,strong) OperationsAssemblyImplementation *operationsAssembly;

@end
```

All four are included in Info.plist
[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9yp1.png)

But when i'm trying to access operationsAssembly inside servicesAssembly it's an instance of TyphoonCollaboratingAssemblyProxy class so i can't access it's methods. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Non-activated assemblies return definitions. Activated assemblies return built instances. They do that by using a proxy that forwards method invocations to TyphoonComponentFactory, which has recipes for emitting built instances. It should just work.

Comment: Yes, i understand that, but shouldn't they be activated if included in TyphoonInitialAssemblies?

Comment: Yes plist assemblies should be already activated. Want to send a sample?